# How can I return a value from an AsyncTask that makes another asynchronous call in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an asyncTask for making a request to a youtube API. I am trying to return data from the AsyncTask but it freezes as soon as I execute the youtube request

```
public class FindPreviousPlaylistTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlaylistListResponse> {

    @Override
    protected PlaylistListResponse  doInBackground(Void... params) {

            YouTube.Playlists.List playlistsListMineRequest = getYoutube().playlists()
                    .list("snippet,contentDetails")
                    .setMine(true)
                    .setMaxResults(50L);

            ArrayList<Playlist> foundPlaylists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

            PlaylistListResponse response = playlistsListMineRequest.execute(); //Async call

            return response;

        return null;
    }

}
```

.

```
private PlaylistListResponse getPlaylist(){
   FindPreviousPlaylistTask previousPlaylistTask = new FindPreviousPlaylistTask();
   return previousPlaylistTask.execute().get();
}
```

The whole point of the AsyncTask is make the youtube call outside of the main thread, but now I can't return the value of the youtube call.

If I call `previousPlaylistTask.execute()` without `.get()` it works fine

Comment: Create Custom Listener using `interface`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Not sure what you mean. Can you show me a quick example

Comment: Example : [Creating Custom Listeners](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return result will available in onPostExecute() method or you can create an Interface like this

```
 public class FindPreviousPlaylistTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, 
  PlaylistListResponse> {

   public interface AsyncResponse {
         void processFinish(PlaylistListResponse output);
      }
  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

   public FindPreviousPlaylistTask (AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected PlaylistListResponse  doInBackground(Void... params) {

        YouTube.Playlists.List playlistsListMineRequest = 
     getYoutube().playlists()
                .list("snippet,contentDetails")
                .setMine(true)
                .setMaxResults(50L);

        ArrayList<Playlist> foundPlaylists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

        PlaylistListResponse response = playlistsListMineRequest.execute(); 
     //Async call

        return response;

     return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(PlaylistListResponse result) {
    delegate.processFinish(result);
  }

}
```

you can call it like this

```
private void getPlaylist(){

  FindPreviousPlaylistTask previousPlaylistTask=new 
    FindPreviousPlaylistTask( new AsyncResponse(){
    @Override
    void processFinish(PlaylistListResponse output){
        //here your AsyncTask response will be available in output valiable
        //you can do whatever you want here
     }

  }).execute();

}
```

Comment: `return response;`. No that will not contain 'output'. Your function will return with uninitialised response before doInBackground has even started.

Comment: The output should be handled in processFinish().

Answer (score 2):

Your app freezes because you are calling `get()` which makes current thread wait for task to finish and get result. You should instead use the result given in `onPostExecure(PlaylistListResponse result)`.

```
public class FindPreviousPlaylistTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlaylistListResponse> {

    @Override
    protected PlaylistListResponse  doInBackground(Void... params) {

            YouTube.Playlists.List playlistsListMineRequest = getYoutube().playlists()
                    .list("snippet,contentDetails")
                    .setMine(true)
                    .setMaxResults(50L);

            ArrayList<Playlist> foundPlaylists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

            PlaylistListResponse response = playlistsListMineRequest.execute(); //Async call

            return response;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlaylistListResponse result) {
        // Do something with your result
    }

}
```